# Passing values in Userform

Tags: excel, userform, vba

I have a problem with passing values. First of I tried to passing them between Userform and module. I thought it must have been an issue so I put subroutine in the same userform. Still my value is passed but it does not pass back to the first subroutine. I am getting lost what is happening...

```
Private Sub rob_wnioski_but_Click()

Dim wnioski_path As String

wybor_pliku klient_path:="", opcja:=1

MsgBox (klient_path)

End Sub


Private Sub wybor_pliku(ByRef klient_path As String, opcja As Integer)

Start.Hide   

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    .AllowMultiSelect = False 'tylko jeden plik

    If .Show = True Then: klient_path = .SelectedItems(1)

End With

Unload Start

End Sub
```

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Did you put a breakpoint on the `If .Show = True` line, in order to determine that a value is being correctly assigned to the `klient_path` variable within the `wybor_pliku` routine?

Comment: `klient_path` is assigned within `wybor_pliku` routine, however after it ends it should be passed back to `rob_wnioski_but_Click` but it is not. I saw something like this here: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/byrefbyval.aspx but I cannot reproduce it in my example. This routime is of course within Userform Forms.

Comment: I understand where `klient_path` is assigned. Now, please answer my question: what have you done to be *sure* that a value is actually assigned *to* that variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a variable to wybor_pliku. What you are doing is to pass a literal (empty string). You need to declare klient_path as a variable in the _Click procedure, then call wybor_pliku like this:

```
wybor_pliku klient_path, opcja:=1
```

Comment: It works! So in other words if I pass any defined value like I did in question it will not update? Am I correct? In your example `opcja` will not change even if I set it different value in subroutine `wybor_pliku` ?